# Best approach to update on chain data

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I'm keeping a record of player points on the Solana blockchain. Every time a player scores a point on my frontend app I want to update their point on a PDA account on the Solana blockchain. Only the admin has the right to update points due to access control. What approach should I take when creating my front-end react app? I want the points to be updated every time a user scores a point without having to manually sign the transaction through the admin phantom wallet

Answer (score 2):

> I want the the points to be updated every time a user scores a point without having to manually sign the transaction through the admin phantom wallet

What it sounds like you want is to have some authenticated session, perhaps using signatures of Solana addresses, between your users and a server where your admin wallet is hosted. Users wouldn't be doing any blockchain transactions over this session (but you could still have them do some on-chain interactions as setup to your game, etc), only requesting activity from your admin server.

If your admin server "believes" the request, because the session is authenticated and the user is playing "by the rules", etc, then the server could construct, sign, and send the transaction to update the score.

Phantom wallet is not an appropriate signing mechanism for your admin wallet, you'll need to work with either a keypair file or have a means of passing in a secret from stdin, where your server's runtime can then sign and send transactions as it pleases.

Comment: How do I make this secure and ensure that my private key wouldn't be hacked? Also I'm a complete rookie so would nodejs be appropriate for backend server?

Comment: NodeJS is fine and Typescript is the most supported language for client-side Solana. 

Your question about keeping your deployment secure is broad and largely not a Solana topic. You should use some sort of secret management system (AWS, Kubernetes, and the like all have their own versions of this), and never keep the private key on your server host in the clear. If you are a newbie, you would be wise not to trust yourself to do this kind of work properly, and you should hire someone who is an expert in secure deployment.